# AngularJS loop variable not working as expected

Tags: angularjs

The JSFiddle for this code is at http://jsfiddle.net/done_merson/x3r4o0aj/7/.
Here is the HTML:

```
    <div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
    <div ng-repeat="category in model.categories"> <span> Category: {{ category.name }} </span>

        <p ng-repeat="subCategory in getSubCategories(category.Id)">{{ subCategory.name }}
            <p ng-repeat="subsubCategory in getSubSubCategories(subCategory.name)">{{ subsubCategory.amount }}
        </p> 
    </div>
</div>
```

And here is the the JS code:

```
angular.module("app", [])
    .controller('ctrl', ['$scope',

function ($scope) {
    $scope.model = {
        categories: [{
            "Id": 1,
            name: '1'
        }, {
            "Id": 2,
            name: '2'
        }],
        subCategories: [{
            "parentId": 1,
            name: 'a1'
        }, {
            "parentId": 1,
            name: 'a2'
        },
                       {
            "parentId": 2,
            name: 'a3'
        }],
        subsubcategories:[
            {
            "name":'a1',
            "amount": 43
          },
          {
            "name":'a1',
            "amount": 21
          },
          {
            "name":"a2",
            "amount": 25
          },
          {
            "name":"a3",
            "amount": 33
          },
          {
            "name":"a3",
            "amount": 17
          }
          
        ]
    }
    $scope.getSubCategories = function(parentId){
        var result = [];
        for(var i = 0 ; i < $scope.model.subCategories.length ; i++){
            if(parentId === $scope.model.subCategories[i].parentId){
                result.push($scope.model.subCategories[i]);               
            }
        }
        console.log(parentId)
        return result;
    }
    $scope.getSubSubCategories = function(name){
    
        var subresult = [];
        for(var i = 0 ; i < $scope.model.subsubcategories.length ; i++){
            if(name === $scope.model.subsubcategories[i].name){
                subresult.push($scope.model.subsubcategories[i]);               
            }
        }
        console.log(name)
        return subresult;
    }
}])
```

The first loop is working correctly (model.categories) but inner loop for the next loop is passing  undefined for subCategory.name. Can I not pass the subCategory to the next loop? Or am I doing something wrong? What I am really trying to do is be able to create a report like you can with Access or ReportServer where you have grouping and summary of data. If anyone has any code like, I would love to see an example too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check now

```js
 
angular.module("app", [])
    .controller('ctrl', ['$scope',

function ($scope) {
    $scope.model = {
        categories: [{
            "Id": 1,
            name: '1'
        }, {
            "Id": 2,
            name: '2'
        }],
        subCategories: [{
            "parentId": 1,
            name: 'a1'
        }, {
            "parentId": 1,
            name: 'a2'
        },
                       {
            "parentId": 2,
            name: 'a3'
        }],
        subsubcategories:[
            {
            "name":'a1',
            "amount": 43
          },
          {
            "name":'a1',
            "amount": 21
          },
          {
            "name":"a2",
            "amount": 25
          },
          {
            "name":"a3",
            "amount": 33
          },
          {
            "name":"a3",
            "amount": 17
          }
          
        ]
    }
    $scope.getSubCategories = function(parentId){
        var result = [];
        for(var i = 0 ; i < $scope.model.subCategories.length ; i++){
            if(parentId === $scope.model.subCategories[i].parentId){
                result.push($scope.model.subCategories[i]);               
            }
        }
        console.log(parentId)
        return result;
    }
    $scope.getSubSubCategories = function(name){
    
        var subresult = [];
        for(var i = 0 ; i < $scope.model.subsubcategories.length ; i++){
            if(name === $scope.model.subsubcategories[i].name){
                subresult.push($scope.model.subsubcategories[i]);               
            }
        }
        console.log(name)
        return subresult;
    }
}])
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
    <div ng-repeat="category in model.categories"> <span> Category: {{ category.name }} </span>

        <p ng-repeat="subCategory in getSubCategories(category.Id)">{{ subCategory.name }}
            <span ng-repeat="subsubCategory in getSubSubCategories(subCategory.name)">{{ subsubCategory.amount }} </span>
        </p> 
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have invalid html -- change inner `p` to `span` (also add `</span>`) and it will work.

Errors in html doesnt always result in such tricky things, but its better to always keep it valid.